# How to copy hadoop examples jar from local to hadoop environment?

Tags: linux, hadoop, jar

I'm still newbie with Hadoop.

I've downloaded a cloudera VM image of hadoop and it did not contain hadoop-examples.jar.

I want to manually copy the `hadoop-examples.jar` (I got it from somewhere) and  that is currently in my local disk, to the hadoop environment, specifically to the `usr/jars`

So that if I run `hadoop jar usr/jars/hadoop-examples.jar wordcount words.txt out` it will properly run the jar.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all are you sure there no `hadoop-examples.jar` on a cloudera VM image? Ususally its located at `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/` or at `/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/`. Try to find it via command `find / -name hadoop-*-examples*.jar`. Secondly `hadoop jar` command runs file on your local file system only. So just run something like `hadoop jar /path/to/hadoop-examples.jar wordcount words.txt out` to execute your own jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a file from local filesystem to HDFS location use command

```
hdfs dfs -put /local_disk_path/hadoop-examples.jar /usr/jars/
```

Comment: How does it help the OP to find and run `hadoop-examples.jar`? You know how to run jar file via `hadoop jar` command from HDFS?

Comment: When I try to use put, the below error prompts. Where should I paste the hadoop-examples.jar?
.
`[training@localhost udacity_training]$ ls
code  data  hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar
[training@localhost udacity_training]$ hdfs dfs -put
hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar /usr/jars/
put: /usr/jars/: No such file or directory
[training@localhost udacity_training]$ hdfs dfs -put
hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/
put: /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/: No such file or directory`